# Word for "disliking something at first but then eventually liking it"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms, vocabulary

Single word for "disliking something at first but then eventually liking it."

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but an often used idiom:

> ***[grow on](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grow)***
>   Become gradually more appealing to (someone)
>   *‘This is the kind of album that grows on you with every listen.’*
>
> [***grow on sb***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grow-on-sb)
>   If someone or something grows on you, you like
>   him, her, or it more and more than you did at first:
>   *I wasn't sure about this album when I bought it, but it's really grown on me.*